# C# Timer (TimeSpan) keeps ticking in background (if statements apply when not true)

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to make very simple timer application. I do have a "text" object that's displaying the time after its being converted to string using: **.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss");**

Unfortunately after clicking the button for the whole event to start again - the if statements are being executed as if the timer was just repeating itself (keeping the old tick and text values in background) so if statements actions starts overlapping each other :(.

I have **windows.forms.timer** called **timer2** placed in application. I have also a button called **Button01** and text objects called **Button01text1** & **Button01textleft**. The background colours and timer stop events are based on the text values comparison.

**OLD CODE (invalid usage of string)** :

```
        private void Button01_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
        Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");

        timer2.Tick += (obj, args) =>
        {
            Button01text1.Text =
                (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
                .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
            Button01textleft.Text =
                (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
                .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
            if (Button01text1.Text == "00:00:30")
            {
                Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
                Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
            }
            else if (Button01text1.Text == "00:00:00")
            {
                Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
                Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
                timer2.Stop();
            }
        };

        timer2.Enabled = true;

    }
```

**New code (same issue, but updated thanks to @Dleh)**:

```
        public void Button01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); 

        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Button01text1.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
        Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");

        timer1.Tick += (obj, args) =>
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var timeDifference = (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) - (now - startTime));
            var stringValue = timeDifference.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
            Button01text1 = stringValue;
            Button01textleft.Text = stringValue;
            if (timeDifference <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
            {
                Button01text1.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
                Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
            }
            else if (timeDifference <=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
            {
                Button01text1.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
                Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        };
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Now to give example what happens:

I press button once - it turns green, at 30 seconds left it turns orange at 00 it turns red and stops timer.

If I press button again in the middle of counting (at 40 seconds) it will turn to green & back to 60 seconds, but will change to orange at 50 seconds left (as if the previous tick still count down and reached 30 if I had not clicked the button again).

I am clueless, don't know why its happening - cause it's supposed to be checking the string text values - which shouldn't exist as separate instances...

Any ideas ?_?

**Example Video of what's happening:**  [Screen_recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvo4dvuwbpt1knb/show.avi?dl=0)

Maria

Comment: Just a well intentioned idea: Please do not compare DateTime-format data in string format. This might haunt you later on. Use proper data-types for the data you need in your program.

Comment: Right, that sounds like a good idea - I will take a look how I can compare them in original format asap, still - I don't have any other place to "store" them - that's why I used string Text values - as those are there already being displayed on the screen.

Comment: @MariaNowinska, when clicking on button multiple times, you subscribe to the Tick event many handlers, which have different startTime. those handlers are not synchronized and create stange effects.

Comment: How can restart it and revert timer back to 0, or remove handlers/destroy tick event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private DateTime startTime;

private void timerTick(Object obj, EventArgs args) {
    Button01text1.Text =
        (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
        .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    Button01textleft.Text =
        (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
        .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    if (Button01text1.Text == "00:00:30")
    {
        Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
        Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
    }
    else if (Button01text1.Text == "00:00:00")
    {
        Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
        Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
        timer2.Stop();
    }
}

public void Button01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
    Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
    timer2.Tick -= timerTick;
    timer2.Tick += timerTick;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}
```

Here is a more general solution for multiple timers as promissed:

```
// State of specific counter
private class Counter
{
    public Timer timer;
    public DateTime startTime;
    public Button button;
    public Label text;
    public Label textLeft;
}

// List of counters
private List<Counter> counters;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize counters
    counters = new List<Counter>();
    counters.Add(new Counter { timer = timer1, button = Button01, text = Button01text, textLeft = Button01textleft });
    counters.Add(new Counter { timer = timer2, button = Button02, text = Button02text, textLeft = Button02textleft });
    counters.Add(new Counter { timer = timer3, button = Button03, text = Button03text, textLeft = Button03textleft });
    counters.Add(new Counter { timer = timer4, button = Button04, text = Button04text, textLeft = Button04textleft });
    counters.Add(new Counter { timer = timer5, button = Button05, text = Button05text, textLeft = Button05textleft });
    // Add more if you need

    // Attach handlers
    foreach (var counter in counters)
    {
        counter.timer.Tick += timerTick;
        counter.button.Click += buttonClick;
    }
}

private void timerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Prepare context
    var timer = (Timer) sender;
    var counter = counters.Find(c => c.timer == timer);
    var startTime = counter.startTime;
    var button = counter.button;
    var text = counter.text;
    var textLeft = counter.textLeft;

    // Update time
    var time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime);
    text.Text = time.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    textLeft.Text = time.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    if (time.TotalSeconds < 1)
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
        textLeft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
        timer.Stop();
    }
    else if (time.TotalSeconds < 31)
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
        textLeft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
    }
}

public void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Prepare context
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var counter = counters.Find(c => c.button == button);
    var timer = counter.timer;
    var textLeft = counter.textLeft;

    // Start counter
    counter.startTime = DateTime.Now;
    button.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
    textLeft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I will try it, I have 10 different timers running on same program - do I need to create 10 timerTick functions and 10 button click functions or there is a way to template it? :o

Comment: Those 10 timers, are they working same thing on different buttons?
First, see if this solution works and I will help you make it more general.

Comment: First of all - it is working *_* angel you.

yes imagine like having 10 eggs boiling and running 10 separate timers at different clicks, but the person that puts them on - does not start them same time (so they all count separately on different timers, but doing same thing).

Comment: This is beautiful *_* Thank you very much for all.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is behaving strangely is because every time you click the button, you add another timer tick event to the timer.

This code:

```
timer2.Tick += (obj, args) =>
```

does not simply assign an event to the timer tick, it **adds** an event.

If you change the timer interval to 5000 and put a breakpoint in the tick event, then click the button twice, then you will see it reaches that breakpoint twice every 5 seconds.

Comment: I am sure you are right. How can I delete the old event? Or reset it back to 0?

Comment: She should also use real DateTime objects instead of strings, for example stored in Tag propery.

Comment: Use regular method instead of lambda to easily remove handler with -=

Comment: Hello, I have changed the code according to some comments - still no luck! I am creating whole new timer in every click instance, it just makes numbers go crazy... It seems to be really hard to reset timer back to 0 : /

Comment: You really need to move startTime and tick event handler to outer scope, the way it is now it is impossible to remove event handler and also impossible to work as intended.

Comment: I have 10 timers running in the same program, If I remove them out of this button - how do I start/stop them ? I believe destroying the tick event would sort it out, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be checking the string value of the time. Sometimes ticks will happen and "00:00:30" will not hit perfectly. In addition, every time you do a `DateTime.Now` you will get a slightly different result. You should store get it once and use that for any calculations. You should do comparisons with the time objects not the string value.

You can reinitialize your `timer2` to have it stop / restart.

```
private void Button01_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //reinintialize your timer to stop the old one.
    timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
    Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");

    timer2.Tick += (obj, args) =>
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var timeDifference = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) - (now - startTime));
        var stringValue = timeDifference.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
        Button01text1.Text = stringValue;
        Button01textleft.Text = stringValue;

        if (timeDifference <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
            Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
        }
        else if (timeDifference <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
        {
            Button01.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
            Button01textleft.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    };
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hello, your comment made it all beautiful code-wise, but its still behaving in a wrong way - take a look at this screen recording of the button: [Screen_recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvo4dvuwbpt1knb/show.avi?dl=0)

Comment: I think I am not including something in the code... the type or namespace name Stopwatch could not be found.

Comment: that is just dummy code. however you're initializing `timer2`, just do it again here

Comment: Hi! I have used: Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); and deleted the existing timer from the initialisation of the program. Now it just jumps around and it looks like all tick events just count down over each other (numbers go crazy displaying 30,29,30,29,28,30,29,28,30).

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is you keep adding more event listeners every time you click the button and they are interacting in strange ways.  Because each event can have *multiple* listeners, every one of them fires whenever the event happens (in this case `Tick`).  So the first time you click your button you add lambda A as a listener.  It happily goes along doing what you want.  The next time you click your button, you add a second listener (B) and things get weird.

This is what happens when you start again.  Handler A executes and changes the time to 40 seconds, does its `if` checks and does nothing (the text is already green from your button click and this doesn't change it).  Then handler B executes and immediately changes the time to 60 seconds (also leaves the color alone).  This happens on every tick so both handlers run and change the time back and forth.  After some time A will execute and change the time to 30 seconds.  Then it will change the color to orange.  Then B will run, changing the time back to 50, **but not changing the color to green** (it just leaves the color as whatever it used to be).  This continues, causing the colors to change in strange ways.

To fix this what you need to do is remove the previous handlers when you click your button.

Comment: The explanation sounds really good, I thought its something to do with multiplying events but I couldn't find a way to "clear" the timer... still - it does not allow me to use = null.
**Error 1 The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Tick' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=**

Comment: @MariaNowinska You are correct.  I forgot that only works if the event is something you own.  See my updated answer.

Comment: at the first "Tick" ( **timer2.Tick.GetInvocationList()) ) in **foreach** line it's still giving me exactly same error message. I never thought that time based events can be so hard!

Comment: @MariaNowinska Then apparently I don't remember how to clear all event handlers any more.  You will have to google how to remove them.